# Forcing errors when binding handler not found in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a set of binding handlers that I load up using requireJS and the problem turned out to be that the ko was binding before the handlers had been added - which is fair enough!

The problem I have is that there were no errors when this happens - knockout ignores any binding handlers that have not been registered.

Is there any way to force an error or at least a `console.log` when a binding handler cannot be found?

Example:

```
<div data-bind="madeUpBinding: {}">No error here...</div>
```

This html snippet will be parsed by knockoutjs and show no errors or anything even though `madeUpBinding` has not been registered as a binding handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) on custom bindings you can see why it doesn't give an error. You can use other bindings as a way to pass parameters to your custom binding. In the docs they have a `slideVisible` binder and they use a non-existent `slideDuration` to pass the duration of the animation.

So how do you tell if `madeUpBinding` is a non-existent binding, or a placeholder used to pass parameters to some other binding?

Comment: Ah, fair point... So an error wouldn't be a good idea! I'll wait and see if I get an answer with using `console.log` otherwise this definitely covers the 'why'